# Count Color objects in images

Tags: matlab, counting, image-segmentation

I'm working in image segmentation, testing a lot of different segmentation algorithms, in order to do a comparitive study. At the moment i've implemented the mean shift algorithm. I would like to count the objects segmented in the image. In this images there are two types of objects, with different colors. I have a the manually counting done by specialists so i would like to compare the results.

The result image is:
[image: result.png]

There is any way for me to automize this process?

Can you please help me out!?

Thanks a lot in advance. John

Comment: How are your segmentation results stored? (e.g. some sort of label matrix?).  Have a look at `regionprops` or `bwconncomp`.

Comment: This image is the result of my segmentation. Using `bwconncomp` i have to transform my image in binary. My hope was if I could find some way to count the green and pink objects in this image.

Comment: If you have a segmentation it should be trivial to extract a set of binary images which are "all pink objects" "all green objects", etc.  Your image doesn't look like what I'd call a 'segmentation' as such as it seems to have different shades of pink/purple and green in there, but maybe that's the .png.