# How can i count objects after K-means segmentation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, computer-vision, counting, image-segmentation

I'm working in image segmentation, testing a lot of different segmentation algorithms, in order to do a comparitive study. At the moment i've implemented the k-means algorithm. I would like to automatically count the objects segmented in the image(the pink ones and green ones on each image). I have a manually counting done by specialists so i would like to compare the results.

My input image is:
[image]

My result images are:

[image]
[image]

There is any way for me to automize this process?

Can you please help me out!?

Thanks a lot in advance. John

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are trying to count. I think you should restate your question and additionally should show what you have tried and/or what your desired results should be. It is hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: What about thresholding and using `regionprops`? Please show what you have tried. Also how is this question different than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877499/count-color-objects-in-images) one you asked a few hours ago?

Comment: @ImNt Sorry for not be more explicit. The major problem is, without having a classification method i'm not able to count the objects with accuracy. As i dont have any method to do that i was asking if it is any function or easier method to count the object in the different clusters.

Comment: @Benoit_11 I would prefer not use another segmentation method to do this. Regarding the other post i'm not separating the objects in different images. Its a similar question but not exacly the same

Comment: @Benoit_11 and  ImNt In order to count the objects i haven't tried much, because i'm not able to find much information how to do it :(. Thanks a lot for the help guys

Comment: @John Ok, this is now way clearer to me. Actually this is not a very trivial task and you will not get around using different methods, if you want reliable results. The task is often referred to as **blob detection**.  Take a look at this [MATLAB Central post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/) for example.

Comment: I'm not very experienced using the matlab image processing algorithms. However, I just tried it using the blob detection from the python package scikit-image with the method *Laplacian of Gaussian* and ended up with [this](http://i.imgur.com/KCSWg1a.png) - which I think is pretty close to what you want. The example code I can be found [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_blob.html). If you want a full code example for your case, just tell me and I'll post it (since it is in python I chose to write a comment instead of an answer).

Comment: ... after tweaking some of the parameters I achieved [this](http://i.imgur.com/ghzim5Y.png)

Comment: @lmNt Thanks a lot. But one thing are you able to count  automatically the blobs in the image? I'm looking for this because i have a hudge dataset, 150 images and I have to performed this count on all of them. I really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @John If the images are kind of similar in terms of the sizes of the blobs you should be easily able to determine a set of parameters for the blob detection which should work in most of the cases. I would suggest to verify  the fit of some samples though. If you have found the parameters, you can basically run the script on all of your images and get the number of blobs for all of them.

Comment: @lmNt  All the images have blobs with similar size. My dificulty is to constructe a script to do this task. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76298/discussion-between-lmnt-and-john).

Answer (score 3):

ok, well this method is heavily based on the [link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/) ImNt posted and a bit on matlabs [label2rgb](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/label2rgb.html) example. Im not sure how you cluster the regions but whatever mask/result you got from the clustering should be used as input for my code

The portion that was missing from both of these examples was counting the clusters. The key to getting the number of clusters is using the output of the label function. The label function labels all the connected groups of pixels from 1 to NUMBER_OF_LABELS so using `max(labels(:))` is the same as counting all our clusters

I processed both clusters exactly the same, and normally I wouldn't keep all the intermediate variables around, they are just here so you can see the output after each operation

the basic outline

> 1. Get binary mask (you can customize this)
> 2. fill in any holes
> 3. remove small regions (you can customize this)
> 4. label all regions (this is basically connected component grouping)
> 5. count regions

the matlab code

```
%% creates binary masks for each cluster
cluster1 = imread('cluster1.png');
cluster1 = rgb2gray(cluster1);

cluster2 = imread('cluster2.png');
cluster2 = rgb2gray(cluster2);

%im not sure how you found these clusters 1/2, but using that original mask is
%better than using this 'graythresh' Since I didn't have your original
%clustering output I tried to reconstruct it w
bw1 = im2bw(cluster1,graythresh(cluster1));
bw2 = im2bw(cluster2,graythresh(cluster2));

%alternate method for constructing binary images   
%my_gray_thresh = 0
%bw1 = cluster1 > my_gray_thresh;
%bw2 = cluster2 > my_gray_thresh;

%% the above could be replaced with the output of your clustering alg

%tries to clean up the image a bit, filling in holes
fill_bw1 = imfill(bw1,'holes');
fill_bw2 = imfill(bw2,'holes');

%takes out regions with less than smallest_area_for_dots
smallest_area_for_dots = 5; %you can play with this parameter
large_bw1 = bwareaopen(fill_bw1, smallest_area_for_dots);
large_bw2 = bwareaopen(fill_bw2, smallest_area_for_dots);

%labels the regions, this is essentially connected component analysis 
labels1 = bwlabel(large_bw1);
labels2 = bwlabel(large_bw2);

%plots the labeled image
figure(1)
subplot(2,3,[1 4]);imshow(cluster1);title('original image (grayscale)')
subplot(2,3,2);imshow(bw1);title('bw after threshold')
subplot(2,3,3);imshow(fill_bw1);title('after fill')
subplot(2,3,5);imshow(large_bw1);title('after removing small clusters')
subplot(2,3,6);imshow(label2rgb(labels1));title('labeled clusters')

figure(2)
subplot(2,3,[1 4]);imshow(cluster2);title('original image (grayscale)')
subplot(2,3,2);imshow(bw2);title('bw after threshold')
subplot(2,3,3);imshow(fill_bw2);title('after fill')
subplot(2,3,5);imshow(large_bw2);title('after removing small clusters')
subplot(2,3,6);imshow(label2rgb(labels2));title('labeled clusters')

%the number of figures is equal to the number of labels. since labels are
%numbered 1 to NUM_LABELS doing max will get us the number of dots
num_in_cluster1 = max(labels1(:))
num_in_cluster2 = max(labels2(:))
```

and the matlab desktop output

```
num_in_cluster1 = 243
num_in_cluster2 = 51
```

and the result images
[image]
[image]